# Apache Map All Paths to Root Without Redirect

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

I want Apache to blindly give the root website directory the full URL without a concern for the path. Reason being I have an Angular app that handles routing and it's at the root directory.

I've tried stuff like this:

```
AliasMatch ^/(.+) /var/www/html/mywebsite.com
```

But it always results in an infinite loop.

Essentially, I just want to disable path-directory resolution.

EDIT: I should also clarify that I have multiple sites hosted on the same machine and still want that to function. I just don't want directory routing from within a single website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish what I want while also having the neat side effect of allowing me to still have assets that can be reached through directory navigation:

```
FallbackResource /
```

Will use the root directory without changing the URL when no such directory the path specifies exists.